# failed to read publicKey property in navigator.credentials.create

Tags: javascript, webauthn

I have following java script code which is called from html page when I receive data from server as part of test code to check my understanding is right.

```
// sample arguments for registration
const createCredentialDefaultArgs = {
  publicKey: {
    
    // User:
    user: {
      id: new Uint8Array(16),
      name: "carina.p.anand@example.com",
      displayName: "Carina P. Anand",
    },

    pubKeyCredParams: [
      {
        type: "public-key",
        alg: -7,
      },
      {
        type: "public-key",
        alg: -257,
      }
    ],
    timeout: 60000,
    challenge: new Uint8Array([
      // must be a cryptographically random number sent from a server
      0x8c, 0x0a, 0x26, 0xff, 0x22, 0x91, 0xc1, 0xe9, 0xb9, 0x4e, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x1a,
      0x98, 0x6a, 0x73, 0x71, 0x9d, 0x43, 0x48, 0xd5, 0xa7, 0x6a, 0x15, 0x7e, 0x38,
      0x94, 0x52, 0x77, 0x97, 0x0f, 0xef,
    ]).buffer,
  },
};


function registerCeremony() {
    alert("registerCeremony is called ");
    let response = navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialDefaultArgs);
    console.log("reg response ", response);
    alert("reg response ", response);
    alert("create registerCeremony finished");
}
```

Following is error shown

```
reg response  Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to execute 'create' on 'CredentialsContainer': Failed to read the 'publicKey' pro…}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Failed to execute 'create' on 'CredentialsContainer': Failed to read the 'publicKey' property from 'CredentialCreationOptions': Failed to read the 'rp' property from 'PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions': Required member is undefined.
    at registerCeremony (https://Ip address/webauthn_helpers.js:36:39)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (https://IP address /mfareg.htm:13:40)
webauthn_helpers.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'create' on 'CredentialsContainer': Failed to read the 'publicKey' property from 'CredentialCreationOptions': Failed to read the 'rp' property from 'PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions': Required member is undefined.
    at registerCeremony (webauthn_helpers.js:36:39)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (mfareg.htm:13:40)
registerCeremony @ webauthn_helpers.js:36
onclick @ mfareg.htm:13
```

I have defined publicKey, but not sure why we are seeing "Failed to read the 'publicKey' property from 'CredentialCreationOptions error.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.credentials.create()` is asynchronous, so you have to wait for it to resolve before you can read anything in `response`:

```js
async function registerCeremony() {
    alert("registerCeremony is called ");
    let response = await navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialDefaultArgs);
    console.log("reg response ", response);
    alert("reg response ", response);
    alert("create registerCeremony finished");
}
```

You can wait for the Promise to resolve however you want. I used async/await here, but you can of course add a `.then((response) => {})` and read `response` in the callback too.

Edit: Oh, and you failed to specify the `rp` property in your options:

```
Failed to read the 'rp' property from 'PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions': Required member is undefined.
    at registerCeremony (webauthn_helpers.js:36:39)
```

Add the `rp` options as defined here and you should get unstuck:

https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dom-publickeycredentialcreationoptions-rp